# Doctrine 2: If using APC for the Doctrine Meta and/or Query Cache, does APC need to be flushed after each application deploy?

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, apc

For instance, [here is an article on using the doctrine meta and query cache in your Symfony2 application](https://coderwall.com/p/ry1y0a).

I am using Symphony2 so I will use that as an example here. Say you have the following:

```
# config_prod.yml
doctrine:
  orm:
    metadata_cache_driver: apc
    query_cache_driver: apc
```

And in your php.ini you have it set so APC automatically checks each time if a file has changed before using the cache:

```
$ php -i | grep apc
apc.stat => On => On
```

I'm not sure that the last above part matters in this particular case though but let's continue...

So let's say you deploy your Symfony2 application using Capifony:

```
$ cap deploy
```

Do you need to run something like [ornicar/ApcBundle](https://github.com/ornicar/ApcBundle) on each deploy? So after the deploy should one make sure to run:

```
 $ php app/console apc:clear
```

So in short, with `apc.stat=1` in my `php.ini` do I need to worry about flushing the APC cache on deploy for the doctrine query and meta cache?